# SQL loop through columns with name to find max date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for the SQL to loop through 20 columns with dates, to find the max.

My code is kind of bad now:

```
,case 
    when ANNEX_20_DATE is not null and ANNEX_20_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_20_DATE
    when ANNEX_19_DATE is not null and ANNEX_19_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_19_DATE
    when ANNEX_18_DATE is not null and ANNEX_18_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_18_DATE
    when ANNEX_17_DATE is not null and ANNEX_17_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_17_DATE
    when ANNEX_16_DATE is not null and ANNEX_16_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_16_DATE
    when ANNEX_15_DATE is not null and ANNEX_15_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_15_DATE
    when ANNEX_14_DATE is not null and ANNEX_14_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_14_DATE
    when ANNEX_13_DATE is not null and ANNEX_13_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_13_DATE
    when ANNEX_12_DATE is not null and ANNEX_12_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_12_DATE
    when ANNEX_11_DATE is not null and ANNEX_11_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_11_DATE
    when ANNEX_10_DATE is not null and ANNEX_10_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')            then ANNEX_10_DATE
    when ANNEX_9_DATE is not null and ANNEX_9_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_9_DATE
    when ANNEX_8_DATE is not null and ANNEX_8_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_8_DATE
    when ANNEX_7_DATE is not null and ANNEX_7_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_7_DATE
    when ANNEX_6_DATE is not null and ANNEX_6_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_6_DATE
    when ANNEX_5_DATE is not null and ANNEX_5_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_5_DATE
    when ANNEX_4_DATE is not null and ANNEX_4_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_4_DATE
    when ANNEX_3_DATE is not null and ANNEX_3_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_3_DATE
    when ANNEX_2_DATE is not null and ANNEX_2_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_2_DATE
    when ANNEX_1_DATE is not null and ANNEX_1_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd')              then ANNEX_1_DATE
    
    ELSE 'N/A'
```

it's oracle database,
i konow that max date is in filed annex_20

Comment: Which RDMBS are you using? You likely want `GREATEST()` but this isn't supported by all DMBS.

Comment: That sounds like a broken data model to begin with. Those should be rows, not columns

Comment: Your code doesn't find the maximum date, so it is unclear what your question really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `ANNEX_XX_DATE is not null` since `ANNEX_XX_DATE<>...` can't be true if ANNEX_XX_DATE is null, so you can make it easier without it:

```sql
,case 
    when ANNEX_20_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_20_DATE
    when ANNEX_19_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_19_DATE
    when ANNEX_18_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_18_DATE
    when ANNEX_17_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_17_DATE
    when ANNEX_16_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_16_DATE
    when ANNEX_15_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_15_DATE
    when ANNEX_14_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_14_DATE
    when ANNEX_13_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_13_DATE
    when ANNEX_12_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_12_DATE
    when ANNEX_11_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_11_DATE
    when ANNEX_10_DATE<>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_10_DATE
    when ANNEX_9_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_9_DATE
    when ANNEX_8_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_8_DATE
    when ANNEX_7_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_7_DATE
    when ANNEX_6_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_6_DATE
    when ANNEX_5_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_5_DATE
    when ANNEX_4_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_4_DATE
    when ANNEX_3_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_3_DATE
    when ANNEX_2_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_2_DATE
    when ANNEX_1_DATE <>to_date ('19000101', 'yyyy-mm-dd') then ANNEX_1_DATE
    
    ELSE 'N/A'
```

Also I would probably replace it with coalesce(nullif(...)...) to make it easier and shorter:

```sql
coalesce(
   nullif(ANNEX_20_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_19_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_18_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_17_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_16_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_15_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_14_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_13_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_12_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_11_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_10_DATE, date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_9_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_8_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_7_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_6_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_5_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_4_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_3_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_2_DATE , date'1900-01-01'),
   nullif(ANNEX_1_DATE , date'1900-01-01')
)
```